# Android: Issue saving files to removable SD card with encryption ON

Tags: android, mime-types, android-sdcard, storage-access-framework

I have implemented a method for users to save/export files created by my app to any location using the Storage Access Framework.  The architecture is:

1. Use Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to have the user select a directory
2. Use DocumentsContract to create a file in that directory
3. Write the data out to this file

The file is a custom file extension containing custom data, so not a standard file type or mime type.
I am using a Samsung Galaxy S7 with an SD card inserted.  So it does not support Adoptable Storage.  For testing/developing, I am using the My Files system app to open files and a Windows PC with MTP to pull files from the device.

This architecture/code works very well in the following circumstances:

1. Any internal storage location
2. Secondary external storage, unencrypted (removable SD card)

If the SD card is encrypted, I start running into strange issues.

Issue 1: "My Files" system app sees the file as having size 0 bytes and will not open it.

Issue 2: Windows PC also sees the file as having size 0 bytes and will not copy it to my PC over MTP.

Strangely, ES File Explorer can see the file and open it.  DropBox can see the file and upload it.  Issue 1 and 2 above are not present if the SD card is NOT encrypted.

So what is going on here?  I have tried a lot of things to troubleshoot.  My theory is that there's something going on with handling MIME types and Content URIs that behaves differently with encryption on or off - specifically concerning My Files and MTP.  Why would ES File Explorer have no issues seeing this file and opening it?

Here are relevant code snippets:

```
private void selectStoragePathExtended() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DIRECTORY);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DIRECTORY) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            mLocalStorageUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(data.getData(), DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(data.getData()));
        }
    }
}
// This will get called with mLocalStorageUri and a File stored in the app's "ExternalFilesDir"
public static void copyFile(ContentResolver cr, File sourceFile, Uri destFolderUri) throws IOException {
    if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        try {
            source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
            Uri destUri = DocumentsContract.createDocument(cr, destFolderUri, "*/*", sourceFile.getName());

            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = cr.openFileDescriptor(destUri, "w");
            destination = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor()).getChannel();

            if (source.size() > FILE_COPY_MAX_BLOCK) {
                // Transfer file in 128MB blocks
                long position = 0;
                while (destination.transferFrom(source, position, FILE_COPY_MAX_BLOCK) > 0) {
                    position += FILE_COPY_MAX_BLOCK;
                }
            } else {
                long bytesCopied = destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
                if (bytesCopied != source.size()) {
                    String errorMsg = String.format("Error: only %d out of %d bytes copied", bytesCopied, source.size());
                    throw new IOException(errorMsg);
                }
            }
            destination.close();
            pfd.close();
        }
        finally {
            if(source != null) {
                source.close();
            }
            if(destination != null) {
                destination.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Yes I am using a non-standard file copy method with FileChannel, but I have tested with basic FileOutputStreams and other methods with same results.  Also, remember, behavior is normal and working with SD card encryption off. And it actually does work with encryption on, but neither My Files nor Windows MTP can read the file.  Only 3rd party tools like ES File Explorer and DropBox.

Any ideas?  Gotta be a mime type/URI issue?

Comment: Put aside your code for a moment. Can you access *anything* on the encrypted removable storage via your Windows PC? Furthremore, can you access anything that was not put on removable storage by the Windows PC (e.g., copy a file using ES File Explorer)? This feels like it is an issue with Samsung and its support for encrypted removable storage, more so than with your code.

Comment: Great suggestions, it certainly seems like a Samsung issue.  I just ran this test: Using ES File Explorer, I grabbed a file (the same file I am trying to copy with code above, located at sdcard/android/data/[app.domain]/files/...) and copied it to the root of the SD card (ES File Explorer asked me to select the SD card root for permission, I assume using the same Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE).  The file copied and ES File Explorer can open it.  However, My Files cannot and Windows cannot (same behavior as when I do this with my code).

Comment: If I run the same test using My Files (copy the file out of the app files directory and onto the SD card root), everything works.  It must be a Samsung specific issue...?  I have a contact at Samsung I can ask, the tricky part will be formatting the question with the proper explanation.

Comment: "It must be a Samsung specific issue...?" -- it's not tied to your code. I haven't tried encrypted removable storage, and so I can't rule out the possibility that it's broken more widely. I'm not sure Android itself supports encrypted removable storage, though. Neither a Galaxy S8 or a Google Pixel seems to offer encryption of a USB-C flash drive, and no official Google device supports SD cards (which the S8 offers to encrypt, as does an LG K8). So I don't know where official Android support ends and manufacturer-specific support begins in this area.

Comment: To add to my answer to your question: If I copy a file onto the SD card (root) from Windows, I can open this file with My Files and view it (my app can open it and parse it, if sent by My Files).  However, I cannot open the file and parse it programmatically, if the user selects the file via Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.  Probably same issue presenting itself.  Maybe if I capture the intent data that My Files uses when it opens this file with my app, that could give me some clues to work around this?

Comment: Great point about the SD card encryption (AKA encrypted removable storage), I am almost positive it is Samsung that adds that feature.

Comment: "Maybe if I capture the intent data that My Files uses when it opens this file with my app, that could give me some clues to work around this?" -- `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`. It might be interesting to see what `Uri` you get and if it differs structurally from the one that you get from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.

Comment: Quite different.  I get "content://0@media/external/file/2289" from My Files (which works for viewing the file in my app).  But when I select the same file via ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, I get content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/3CDE-1CEC%3A[my-file-name-here]

Comment: That first `Uri` has a fairly bizarre authority. When you say that you "cannot open the file and parse it programmatically" with the second `Uri`, what do you mean? What are the specific symptoms.

Comment: Woah, my app can read the file that it wrote out.  The same file that My Files can't open and reports as 0bytes (and Windows also can't).  There is clearly some disconnect with this Samsung SD card encryption.  Thanks for discussing this with me, by the way.  I know we're building a long comment thread here but it doesn't seem like there will ever be a solution to post.  I am hoping to find a workaround...

Comment: To answer your question about the captured URIs that I posted:  I can open an inputstream and seemingly read the file contents, however, the data is different.  This is a custom file type that my app works with, so it gets reported as corrupted.  When I save the bytes to a new file and view them in an editor, the data is not the same as the original data.  So pointing to an issue with encryption handling I would guess,

Comment: Yes, that doesn't sound good. Feels like they only decrypt for one provider and not another. You could try the `StorageVolume` APIs instead of `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` on Android 7.0+ and see if that gives you better luck on affected devices.

Comment: Good idea, I will take a look at StorageVolume API - haven't used it before.

Comment: Just reporting back: did a quick test run with StorageVolume - didn't get me anywhere.  I started by using the API to request access to the removable SD card storage volume, then used that Uri to create the new file and copy data out - same results.  Worth noting, it looks like the same Uri I'd get if the user selected the SD card root with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, so it seems the same process was followed once I got the Uri.  The only difference in the API is how I got the Uri.  Pretty slick API though, uses a little permissions dialog to request access to the SD card volume at runtime.

Comment: Ah, well, it was worth a shot. Since I don't think Google would use an authority string of `0@media`, my guess is that Samsung has an incomplete implementation of encrypted removable storage, and I don't know what you can do about that.